# How to make php curl multiple api calls faster?

Tags: php, php-curl

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'userdata table url',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
 
));

$response_userdata = curl_exec($curl);
$data_userdata=json_decode($response_menutable,TRUE);
curl_close($curl);


$merged_array = merge_json_decoded_arrays($data_userdata['content']);

$marry=json_decode($merged_array,true);

function merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_userdata) {

foreach ($decode_userdataas $key => $first_value) {
    if($first_value['stocktype']=="grams")
    {
        $decode_userdata[$key]['type']='Kg';
    }
    else
    {
        $decode_userdata[$key]['type']='Pcs';
    }
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'stock available url'.$first_value['key'],
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
 
));

$response_stockavldetails = curl_exec($curl);
$data_stockavldetails=json_decode($response_stockavldetails,TRUE);
curl_close($curl);
    
    foreach ($data_stockavldetails['content'] as $key_two => $second_value) {
     
         $salesallocaqted=0;
             $decode_userdata[$key]['stockstockonhand'] = $second_value['stockbalance'];
         $decode_userdata[$key]['stockkey'] = $second_value['key'];
       
    }
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'user stock table url'.$first_value['key'],
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
 
));

$response_stockoutgoingdetails = curl_exec($curl);
$data_stockoutgoingdetails=json_decode($response_stockoutgoingdetails,TRUE);
curl_close($curl);
         foreach ($data_stockoutgoingdetails['content'] as $key_three => $third_value) { 
         if($third_value['outgoingtype']=="SALES_ALLOCATED"){
             $salesallocaqted+=$third_value['outgoingqty'];
         }
              $decode_userdata[$key]['salesallocated']=$salesallocaqted;
         }
}
$combined_output = json_encode($decode_userdata);
return $combined_output;
}

 echo $merged_array;

?>
```

//$data_userdata

### user data table response

| key | username | usermobile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 1111111111 |
| 2 | bbbb | 2222222222 |
| 3 | cccc | 3333333333 |
| 4 | dddd | 4444444444 |

//$data_stockoutgoingdetails
Here I have been Getting stock available details with the parameter of key from userdata table

### stock available response

| key | username | stockavailable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 11 |

//$data_stockavldetails
*Here I have been Getting stock outgoing details with the parameter of key from userdata table

### user stock table response

| key | username | stockoutgoing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 4 |

//$merged_array
*this is the last table i have been getting after the getting value from 3 table

### end of loop the result of all api

| key | username | usermobile | stockavailable | stockoutgoing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 1111111111 | 11 | 4 |
| 2 | bbbb | 2222222222 | 12 | 5 |
| 3 | cccc | 3333333333 | 13 | 6 |
| 4 | dddd | 4444444444 | 14 | 7 |

### next step

*Then i have been rendering this data into html table using javascript

### Problem

*For getting $merged_array it has been taking 30 seconds to load just for 20 rows i think the problem here is api call inside loop

*Help me to understand what i have been doing wrong and direct me to right path

*I need to load the above data fast as i can

[my sample link] https://docs.google.com/document/d/146f9712eahQ186CoHjnzLFFle8z_VXZ0Fxue8jqCWCM/edit?usp=sharing

comment me if the explanation was not clear

Comment: Is there a way to call the API so that it gives you the stockoutgoing and stockavailable in the same result? Either way your code could be shortened a lot if you moved all your `curl` logic into a separate function. Could you please provide some sample output from the API.

Comment: I can't get stockoutgoing and stockavailable as one response i can get both of then with the value of first response key  .This is sample output
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/146f9712eahQ186CoHjnzLFFle8z_VXZ0Fxue8jqCWCM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't understand much of this code at all since I don't code in PHP, but thinking from a macro perspective, is it possible to base your code on the results from a direct database query? My thinking is that these different hooks into the database could be causing the lag, where a direct database query would be instant, then you use those results for your final output to html ... but for all I know, I could be talking nonsense...